# amplifying/boosting call channel/audio volume

Tags: java, android, opentok, tokbox

We made an application that makes it possible to video call between 2 devices(iOS, Android and web). Using cordova, opentok, nodejs and the cordova-opentok-plugin. During testing we noticed that the sound on an Android device is kind of low, hard to hear the other person talk.

We tested the sound from our application and compared it to tests with Google Hangouts and a normal telephone call. From these tests we can see that the audio is on maximum volume in our application. The audio stream goes through the call channel for all these applications and our own.

We tested the same device with skype, which also goes over the call channel, and the sound on skype is a lot louder than our own application and Google Hangouts or even a normal telephone call.

So it seems Skype has found a way to boost the audio in Android. Does anyone know how we could implemented such kind of a boost/amplify to the audio channel?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which android API level(s) you have tested with ? As this sounds a lot like the automatic ducking feature that android introduced in 8.0, your application can lose Audio focus without being informed and will have its audio ducked if another process requests for Audio focus